# Running a Julia code with Atom

Tags: julia

I'm getting the following error when running a Julia code in Atom. Can someone please help me with this?

```
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile Atom to /Users/xxx/.julia/lib/v0.5/Atom.ji.


in compilecache(::String) at ./loading.jl:593
 in require(::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:422
 in require(::Symbol) at /Applications/Julia-0.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib:?
 in include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:488
 in include_from_node1(::String) at /Applications/Julia-0.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib:?
 in process_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:262
 in _start() at ./client.jl:318
 in _start() at /Applications/Julia-0.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib:?
while loading /Users/xxx/.atom/packages/julia-client/script/boot.jl, in expression starting on line 29
```

Comment: Try opening a REPL and do `using Atom`. Maybe remove the package and reinstall it, all from the REPL.

Comment: Nope.. it didn't work for me...

Comment: Well there's something wrong with your install but it's impossible to tell from the info you've given here.